# how do we read the column headers which can be altered in robot framework?

Tags: javascript, html, testing, selenium, robotframework

I have a very unique problem here. I'm testing a web page using robot framework. There is a table in the webpage with 19 columns and it can be made hidden by selecting only the desired columns. The order in which the columns should appear can also be changed.

I'm able to read the table contents. The challenge here is that I need to keep track of the order in which the columns does appear. Because even though the column header is displayed in the page it isn't inside the table header tag . Its always empty. There is a separate container which contains all the header tags ( all are  ). I'm not sure about how are they making the table headers displayed on the header portion of the table. here is the sample code

```
<th class="x-grid-col-resizer-actioncolumn-1150" style="width: 75px; height: 0px;"></th>  // <-- Empty


<div id="actioncolumn-1150-titleEl" class="x-column-header-inner" style="height: 32px; padding-top: 8px;"><span id="actioncolumn-1150-textEl" class="x-column-header-text">Action</span><div id="actioncolumn-1150-triggerEl" class="x-column-header-trigger"></div></div> <-- one header inside the header container.
```

Here element id's are dynamic. I need to keep track of the order in which the columns does appear. 
Can anyone help me understand how it can be done ?

Comment: So, you just want to grab the header from `div` if exist?

Comment: Yes. I just want to read the header values in order the they appear  (if it appears.)